# am trying to create an array of links with hrefs from a .csv file

Tags: php, html

I have a .csv file and am trying to create a list of links with associated hrefs in an html page. I just want to display :

> page1 (href to test1.html)
>   page2 (href to test2.html)
>   etc.

The code I have so far displays the following :

Page1
//www.test1.co.uk
Page2
//www.test2.co.uk

I just need :

Page1 (links to www.test1.html)
Page2 (links to www.test2.html)

here is the code :

```
<?php



$link = "feed.csv";
$fp = fopen($link, 'r');

    while(($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE) {
    foreach($line as $key => $value) {
        echo "<a href='".$key."'>".$value."</a><br>";
                                      }
                                             }


fclose($fp);
```

?>

the feed.csv file has 2 fields :

Page1, www.test1.html
Page2, www.test2.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use foreach.

Please try following.

```
<?php
    $link = "feed.csv";
    $fp = fopen($link, 'r');

    while(($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE) {
            echo "<a href='".$line[1]."'>".$line[0]."</a><br>";
    }
    fclose($fp);
```